# delete record from table using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to delete a single record based on where condition here is my code below please help me

my code in controller

```
function delete_vehicle_ad($Ad_ID)
    {
        var_dump($Ad_ID);
        $this->classified_ad->del_vehicle_ad($Ad_ID);
        redirect('index.php/account/account-detail/index');
    }
```

My code in Model

```
function del_vehicle_ad($Ad_ID)
    {
        var_dump($Ad_ID);
        $this->db->where('Ad_ID',$Ad_ID);
        $this->db->delete('ad_vehicle');
    }
```

but its not working its not delete my record from the database 
please help me as early as possible

Comment: **as early as possible**? We are not working for you, 'ya know?

Comment: Is the condition met? Is `$Ad_ID` really what you expect?

Comment: the condition is required i got Ad_ID value i check the value with var_dump()

Comment: You could try alternative syntax:
$this->db->delete( 'ad_vehicle', array('Ad_ID' => $Ad_ID) );

Comment: Ok sir i will try this and let you know you whether its working or not thank you sir

Comment: Sorry sir its not working

Comment: Write a select statement to correctly get the records you want to delete. Then change that query to a delete query.

Comment: i got my result thank you very much for response thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The var_dump in your model works ?

if yes, are you sure the table **'ad_vehicle'** and the field **'Ad_ID'** exists (check the syntax) ?

The DB connexion works ?